# Paging: How to find the number of bytes are on each page?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, byte, paging, offset

> Assume the OS is using one level of paging to virtualize memory. The virtual address consists of 24 bits, divided up as follows:
>
> > **| Page #        | Offset
> >     |
> >
> >     | 12 bits         |                     12 bits
> >     |**

**How many bytes are on each page?**

What I know so far:

> Virtual page number bits = 24 bits - 12 bits = 12 bits
>
> Number of pages = 2^12 pages

Please help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Hope it helps.Feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that `Number of pages = 2^12`. Now since there are `12` bits for the `offset`, this means that there are `2^12` bytes of data on each page (provided that memory is byte-addressable).

**Reason**

Since there are `12` bits for the offset, it means that there are `2^12` combinations possible of `0's and 1's` to address memory on each page. If one address is associated with one byte of memory (byte-addressable), then there are `2^12 bytes` on each page.